# MYSQL - copy table error / user permission error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, create-table

I'm trying to copy a table from one database to another and I keep getting errors. I'm not sure which one to troubleshoot specifically or if I'm even going in the right direction. Any ideas?

```
CREATE TABLE _pw_users.items LIKE _users.items;

INSERT INTO _pw_users.items SELECT * FROM _users.items;
```

And I get this error:

```
CREATE command denied to user 'xxxxxx'@'localhost' for table 'items'
```

So I try to allow permissions with this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `_pw_users`.* TO 'xxxxxx'@'localhost'
```

And I get this error:

```
"#1044 - Access denied for user 'xxxxxx'@'localhost' to database '_pw_users' "
```

I'm not sure where I should go from here.

Comment: You user has no permission to make changes to that database, you need to use the admin user to grant the privileges

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing with the 2nd code that I enter?

Comment: You cannot grant yourself permission, when you don't have permission in the first place. You need to connect as an admin user that has permission to make changes, you can then grant permissions to a normal user for that database.

Comment: Are you sure that is correct? How do I connect as an admin? I thought I was already.

Comment: If anyone could grant themselves permissions on any database at any time, what would be the point in permissions? If your user had permission you wouldn't need to grant permission, if your user doesn't, you can't. Your user probably only has permissions on your old database, not your new one.

Comment: You're probably right. So how do I give myself permissions?